# Apache CGI, catch all requests for directory

Tags: apache, cgi, apache-config

Is it possible to configure Apache CGI so that all requests in one directory end up going to one script?

So let's say a browser requests `mysite.com/cgi-bin/doesnt_exist`  it would end up going to `myscript.cgi`, or if the request had been anything in `cgi-bin`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a htaccess file inside cgi-bin containing:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /cgi-bin/myscript.cgi
```

?